# The MVC pattern and Swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

One of the design patterns which I find most difficult to get a real grasp of in "real Swing life" is the MVC pattern. I've been through quite a few of the posts at this site which discuss the pattern, but I still do not feel that I have a clear understanding of how to take advantage of the pattern in my Java Swing application.

Let's say that I have a JFrame which contains a table, a couple of text fields and a few buttons. I would probably use a TableModel to "bridge" the JTable with an underlying data model. However, all functions responsible for clearing fields, validating fields, locking fields along with button actions would usually go directly in the JFrame. However, doesn't that mix the Controller and View of the pattern?

As far as I can see, I manage to get the MVC pattern "correctly" implemented when looking at the JTable (and the model), but things get muddy when I look at the entire JFrame as a whole.

I'd really like to hear how others go about with regard to this. How do you go about when you need to display a table, a couple of fields and some buttons to a user using the MVC pattern?

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979).

Comment: For anyone else coming to this party - [Swing is NOT a pure MVC](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html) - it borrows heavy from the concept, but "collapses" the "view and controller" together

Answer (score 115, accepted):

A book I'd highly recommend to you for MVC in swing would be "Head First Design Patterns" by Freeman and Freeman. They have a highly comprehensive explanation of MVC.

> **Brief Summary**
>
> 1. **You're the user--you interact with the view.** The view is your window to the model. When you do something to the view (like click the
>      Play button) then the view tells the controller what you did. It's the
>      controller's job to handle that.
> 2. **The controller asks the model to change its state.** The controller takes your actions and interprets them. If you click on a
>      button, it's the controller's job to figure out what that means and
>      how the model should be manipulated based on that action.
> 3. **The controller may also ask the view to change.** When the controller receives an action from the view, it may need to tell the
>      view to change as a result. For example, the controller could enable
>      or disable certain buttons or menu items in the interface.
> 4. **The model notifies the view when its state has changed.** When something changes in the model, based either on some action you took
>      (like clicking a button) or some other internal change (like the next
>      song in the playlist has started), the model notifies the view that
>      its state has changed.
> 5. **The view asks the model for state.** The view gets the state it displays directly from the model. For instance, when the model
>      notifies the view that a new song has started playing, the view
>      requests the song name from the model and displays it. The view might
>      also ask the model for state as the result of the controller
>      requesting some change in the view.

[image]
[Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) (In case you're wondering what a "creamy controller" is, think of an Oreo cookie, with the controller being the creamy center, the view being the top biscuit and the model being the bottom biscuit.)

Um, in case you're interested, you could download a fairly entertaining song about the MVC pattern from [here](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/media.php)!

One issue you may face with Swing programming involves amalgamating the SwingWorker and EventDispatch thread with the MVC pattern. Depending on your program, your view or controller might have to extend the SwingWorker and override the `doInBackground()` method where resource intensive logic is placed. This can be easily fused with the typical MVC pattern, and is typical of Swing applications.

**EDIT #1**:

Additionally, it is important to consider MVC as a sort of composite of various patterns. For example, your model could be implemented using the Observer pattern (requiring the View to be registered as an observer to the model) while your controller might use the Strategy pattern.

**EDIT #2**:

I would additionally like to answer specifically your question. You should display your table buttons, etc in the View, which would obviously implement an ActionListener. In your `actionPerformed()` method, you detect the event and send it to a related method in the controller (remember- the view holds a reference to the controller). So when a button is clicked, the event is detected by the view, sent to the controller's method, the controller might directly ask the view to disable the button or something. Next, the controller will interact with and modify the model (which will mostly have getter and setter methods, and some other ones to register and notify observers and so on). As soon as the model is modified, it will call an update on registered observers (this will be the view in your case). Hence, the view will now update itself.

Comment: I've actual read the book, but I have found it hard to apply the pattern to SWING. I have also read a couple of places have read that a JFrame also can be seen as both representing a view and a controller.

Comment: ... the JFrame is a component, and not a leaf. typically, updates made by the controller are sent to the JFrame, which takes care of the rest, hence, this might give the illusion of it being a controller, but in reality, this is not the case because it has not changed the model, only the view. if your JFrame has somehow changed the model directly- you're doing it wrong.

Comment: ... again, the keyword here is "directly". in your case, you might listen to mouseclicks on the table, and send the logic to methods in the controller which modify the table model.

Comment: @DhruvGairola The second point description is for the third point, the third and for points have the same duplicated descriptions. Can you correct them please.

Comment: That song is a classic! `=D`

Answer (score 38):

Not a fan of the idea that the view should be the one to be notified by the model when its data changes. I would delegate that functionality to the controller. In that case, if you change the application logic, you don't need to interfere to the view's code. The view's task is only for the applications components + layout nothing more nothing less. Layouting in swing is already a verbose task, why let it interfere with the applications logic?

My idea of MVC (which I'm currently working with, so far so good) is :

1. The view is the dumbest of the three. It doesn't know anything about the controller and the model. Its concern is only the swing components' prostethics and layout.
2. The model is also dumb, but not as dumb as the view. It performs the following functionalities.

- a. when one of its setter is called by the controller, it will fire notification to its listeners/observers (like I said, I would deligate this role to the controller). I prefer [SwingPropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/SwingPropertyChangeSupport.html) for achieving this since its already optimized for this purpose.
- b. database interaction functionality.

3. A very smart controller. Knows the view and the model very well. The controller has two functionalities:

- a. It defines the action that the view will execute when the user interacts to it.
- b. It listens to the model. Like what I've said, when the setter of the model is called, the model will fire notification to the controller. It's the controller's job to interpret this notification. It might need to reflect the change to the view.

### Code Sample

The View :

Like I said creating the view is already verbose so just create your own implementation :)

```
interface View{
    JTextField getTxtFirstName();
    JTextField getTxtLastName();
    JTextField getTxtAddress();
}
```

It's ideal to interface the three for testability purposes. I only provided my implementation of Model and Controller.

The Model :

```
public class MyImplementationOfModel implements Model{
    ...
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChangeFirer;
    private String address;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public MyImplementationOfModel() {
        propChangeFirer = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }
    public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener prop) {
        propChangeFirer.addPropertyChangeListener(prop);
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){
        String oldVal = this.address;
        this.address = address;
        
        //after executing this, the controller will be notified that the new address has been set. Its then the controller's
        //task to decide what to do when the address in the model has changed. Ideally, the controller will update the view about this
        propChangeFirer.firePropertyChange("address", oldVal, address);
    }
    ...
    //some other setters for other properties & code for database interaction
    ...
}
```

The Controller :

```
public class MyImplementationOfController implements PropertyChangeListener, Controller{

    private View view;
    private Model model;

    public MyImplementationOfController(View view, Model model){
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
        
        //register the controller as the listener of the model
        this.model.addListener(this);
        
        setUpViewEvents();
    }

    //code for setting the actions to be performed when the user interacts to the view.
    private void setUpViewEvents(){
        view.getBtnClear().setAction(new AbstractAction("Clear") { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                model.setFirstName("");
                model.setLastName("");
                model.setAddress("");
            }
        });
        
        view.getBtnSave().setAction(new AbstractAction("Save") { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ...
                //validate etc.
                ...
                model.setFirstName(view.getTxtFName().getText());
                model.setLastName(view.getTxtLName().getText());
                model.setAddress(view.getTxtAddress().getText());
                model.save();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
        String propName = evt.getPropertyName();
        Object newVal = evt.getNewValue();
        
        if("address".equalsIgnoreCase(propName)){
            view.getTxtAddress().setText((String)newVal);
        }
        //else  if property (name) that fired the change event is first name property
        //else  if property (name) that fired the change event is last name property
    }
}
```

The Main, where the MVC is setup :

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        View view = new YourImplementationOfView();
        Model model = new MyImplementationOfModel();
        
        ...
        //create jframe
        //frame.add(view.getUI());
        ...
        
        //make sure the view and model is fully initialized before letting the controller control them.
        Controller controller = new MyImplementationOfController(view, model);
        
        ...
        //frame.setVisible(true);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting but it is less efficient when a single entity model is displayed in multiple views... Then your design may lead to a "big controller" handling a single model but managing all related views. And it becomes even trickier if you try to reuse a set of "small model", thanks to an aggregation into a "large model" because a view displays information dispatched in multiple "small model" entities.

Comment: @onepotato I just tried your codes. When I press a button, I can get the codes in setUpViewEvents() to fire. However, when I do a model.setSomething(123), the codes in propertyChange do not get fired. I even put a println directly under Object newVal = evt.getNewValue(); and it doesn't print.

Comment: This is NOT the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architectural pattern, but the **closely related** [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) (Model-View-Presenter) pattern. In a typical MVC, **it is precisely the model's job to notify the view when it has changed**, exactly what you "don't like". Look at [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#mediaviewer/File:MVC-Process.svg) to see how interactions in a typical MVC work.

Answer (score 35):

The MVC pattern is a model of how a user interface can be structured.
Therefore it defines the 3 elements Model, View, Controller:

- **Model** A model is an abstraction of something that is presented to the user. In swing you have a differentiation of gui models and data models. GUI models abstract the state of a ui component like [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html). Data models abstract structured data that the ui presents to the user like [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).
- **View** The view is a ui component that is responsible for presenting data to the user. Thus it is responsible for all ui dependent issues like layout, drawing, etc. E.g. [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).
- **Controller** A controller encapsulates the application code that is executed in order to an user interaction (mouse motion, mouse click, key press, etc.). Controllers might need input for their execution and they produce output. They read their input from models and update models as result of the execution. They might also restructure the ui (e.g. replace ui components or show a complete new view). However they must not know about the ui compoenents, because you can encapsulate the restructuring in a separate interface that the controller only invokes. In swing a controller is normally implemented by an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) or [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html).

**Example**

- Red = model
- Green = view
- Blue = controller

[image]

When the `Button` is clicked it invokes the `ActionListener`. The `ActionListener` only depends on other models. It uses some models as it's input and others as it's result or output. It's like method arguments and return values. The models notify the ui when they get updated. So there is no need for the controller logic to know the ui component. The model objects don't know the ui. The notification is done by an observer pattern. Thus the model objects only know that there is someone who wants to get notified if the model changes.

In java swing there are some components that implement a model and controller as well. E.g. the [javax.swing.Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html). It implements a ui model (properties: enablement, small icon, name, etc.) and is a controller because it extends [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

A **detailed explanation, example application and source code**: https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/.

**MVC basics in less than 260 lines:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("MVC example");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(640, 300);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        PersonService personService = new PersonServiceMock();

        DefaultListModel searchResultListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        DefaultListSelectionModel searchResultSelectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
        searchResultSelectionModel
                .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        Document searchInput = new PlainDocument();

        PersonDetailsAction personDetailsAction = new PersonDetailsAction(
                searchResultSelectionModel, searchResultListModel);
        personDetailsAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Person Details");

        Action searchPersonAction = new SearchPersonAction(searchInput,
                searchResultListModel, personService);
        searchPersonAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Search");

        Container contentPane = mainFrame.getContentPane();

        JPanel searchInputPanel = new JPanel();
        searchInputPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextField searchField = new JTextField(searchInput, null, 0);
        searchInputPanel.add(searchField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        searchField.addActionListener(searchPersonAction);

        JButton searchButton = new JButton(searchPersonAction);
        searchInputPanel.add(searchButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JList searchResultList = new JList();
        searchResultList.setModel(searchResultListModel);
        searchResultList.setSelectionModel(searchResultSelectionModel);

        JPanel searchResultPanel = new JPanel();
        searchResultPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollableSearchResult = new JScrollPane(searchResultList);
        searchResultPanel.add(scrollableSearchResult, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel selectionOptionsPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton showPersonDetailsButton = new JButton(personDetailsAction);
        selectionOptionsPanel.add(showPersonDetailsButton);

        contentPane.add(searchInputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(searchResultPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(selectionOptionsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class PersonDetailsAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8816163868526676625L;

    private ListSelectionModel personSelectionModel;
    private DefaultListModel personListModel;

    public PersonDetailsAction(ListSelectionModel personSelectionModel,
            DefaultListModel personListModel) {
        boolean unsupportedSelectionMode = personSelectionModel
                .getSelectionMode() != ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION;
        if (unsupportedSelectionMode) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "PersonDetailAction can only handle single list selections. "
                            + "Please set the list selection mode to ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION");
        }
        this.personSelectionModel = personSelectionModel;
        this.personListModel = personListModel;
        personSelectionModel
                .addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = (ListSelectionModel) e
                                .getSource();
                        updateEnablement(listSelectionModel);
                    }
                });
        updateEnablement(personSelectionModel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int selectionIndex = personSelectionModel.getMinSelectionIndex();
        PersonElementModel personElementModel = (PersonElementModel) personListModel
                .get(selectionIndex);

        Person person = personElementModel.getPerson();
        String personDetials = createPersonDetails(person);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, personDetials);
    }

    private String createPersonDetails(Person person) {
        return person.getId() + ": " + person.getFirstName() + " "
                + person.getLastName();
    }

    private void updateEnablement(ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel) {
        boolean emptySelection = listSelectionModel.isSelectionEmpty();
        setEnabled(!emptySelection);
    }

}

class SearchPersonAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4083406832930707444L;

    private Document searchInput;
    private DefaultListModel searchResult;
    private PersonService personService;

    public SearchPersonAction(Document searchInput,
            DefaultListModel searchResult, PersonService personService) {
        this.searchInput = searchInput;
        this.searchResult = searchResult;
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String searchString = getSearchString();

        List<Person> matchedPersons = personService.searchPersons(searchString);

        searchResult.clear();
        for (Person person : matchedPersons) {
            Object elementModel = new PersonElementModel(person);
            searchResult.addElement(elementModel);
        }
    }

    private String getSearchString() {
        try {
            return searchInput.getText(0, searchInput.getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}

class PersonElementModel {

    private Person person;

    public PersonElementModel(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return person.getFirstName() + ", " + person.getLastName();
    }
}

interface PersonService {

    List<Person> searchPersons(String searchString);
}

class Person {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

}

class PersonServiceMock implements PersonService {

    private List<Person> personDB;

    public PersonServiceMock() {
        personDB = new ArrayList<Person>();
        personDB.add(new Person(1, "Graham", "Parrish"));
        personDB.add(new Person(2, "Daniel", "Hendrix"));
        personDB.add(new Person(3, "Rachel", "Holman"));
        personDB.add(new Person(4, "Sarah", "Todd"));
        personDB.add(new Person(5, "Talon", "Wolf"));
        personDB.add(new Person(6, "Josephine", "Dunn"));
        personDB.add(new Person(7, "Benjamin", "Hebert"));
        personDB.add(new Person(8, "Lacota", "Browning "));
        personDB.add(new Person(9, "Sydney", "Ayers"));
        personDB.add(new Person(10, "Dustin", "Stephens"));
        personDB.add(new Person(11, "Cara", "Moss"));
        personDB.add(new Person(12, "Teegan", "Dillard"));
        personDB.add(new Person(13, "Dai", "Yates"));
        personDB.add(new Person(14, "Nora", "Garza"));
    }

    public List<Person> searchPersons(String searchString) {
        List<Person> matches = new ArrayList<Person>();

        if (searchString == null) {
            return matches;
        }

        for (Person person : personDB) {
            if (person.getFirstName().contains(searchString)
                    || person.getLastName().contains(searchString)) {
                matches.add(person);
            }

        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

[image: MVC Basics Screencast]

Comment: I like this answer +1 , for mention `Action` as `Controller` in fact i guess all `EventListener` are controllers..

Comment: @nachokk Yes, indeed. As I said `A controller encapsulates the application code that is executed in order to an user interaction`. Moving the mouse, clicking on a component, press a key, etc. are all user interactions. To make it more clear I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create model in a separate, plain Java class, and controller in another.

Then you can have Swing components on top of that. `JTable` would be one of the views (and table model would *de facto* be part of the view - it would only translate from the "shared model" to `JTable`).

Whenever the table is edited, its table model tells the "main controller" to update something. However, the controller should know nothing about the table. So the call should look more like: `updateCustomer(customer, newValue)`, not `updateCustomer(row, column, newValue)`.

Add a listener (observer) interface for the shared model. Some components (e.g. your table) could implement it directly. Another observer could be the controller that coordinates button availability etc.

---

That's one way to do it, but of course you can simplify or extend it if its an overkill for your use case.

You can merge the controller with model and have the same class process updates and maintain component availability. You even can make the "shared model" a `TableModel` (though if it's not only used by the table, I would recommend at least providing a friendlier API that doesn't leak table abstractions)

On the other hand, you can have complex interfaces for updates (`CustomerUpdateListener`, `OrderItemListener`, `OrderCancellationListener`) and dedicated controller (or mediator) only for coordination of different views.

It depends on how complicated your problem is.

Comment: About 90% of all views consists of a table where the user can select an element to edit. What I have done until now is that I have a data model through which all CRUD operations goes. I use a TableModel to adapt the data model to the JTable. So, to update an element i would invoke table.getModel().getModel().update(Element e). In other words, the JTable sort of is the Controller right now. All button actions are placed in separate classes (i reuse them in different contexts) and do their work through the methods of the underlying model. Is that a viable design?

Answer (score 2):

For proper separation, you would typically have a controller class that the Frame class would delegate to. There are various ways to set up the relationships between the classes - you could implement a controller and extend it with your main view class, or use a standalone controller class that the Frame calls when events occur. The view would typically receive events from the controller by implementing a listener interface.

Sometimes one or more parts of the MVC pattern are trivial, or so 'thin' that it adds unnecessary complexity to separate them out. If your controller is full of one line calls, having it in a separate class can end up obfuscating the underlying behaviour. For instance, if the all of the events you are handling are related to a TableModel and are simple add and delete operations you might choose to implement all of the table manipulation functions within that model (as well as the callbacks necessary to display it in the JTable). It's not true MVC, but it avoids adding complexity where it isn't needed.

However you implement it, remember to JavaDoc your classes, methods and packages so that the components and their relationships are properly described!

Comment: @AndyT while most of your explanation is good, i have an issue with your advice on combining the model with the controller. what if i want to suddenly change the controller? now i find that you've coupled the model with the controller and need to modify the model as well. your code is no longer extensible. however short your controller, i would'nt combine it with a model. or a view.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree - it depends a lot on your application. If your model is no more sophisticated than a List object, and your controller does little more than add and remove elements, creating three separate classes (List model, Controller and adaptor for your model to work with the JTable) is overkill. It's easier to refactor it out in the unlikely case that you need a different controller, than to churn out shim classes for the sake of some unknown future need.

Comment: @AndyT agreed, perhaps if you're application is small, this might be the fastest way. but for extensibility's sake (consider if the addition is not made by the same programmer), it might work as a disadvantage.

Comment: @AndyT: I do not know how long you have been developing software, but your posting demonstrates that you have embraced the KISS principle. Far too many smart, but inexperienced Java developers embrace designs patterns like they are the bible (design patterns are little more than high-level cut-and-paste programming).  In most cases, taking a purist approach by building separate controller and view classes only serves to make maintenance by anyone other than the original developer a nightmare for programs larger than couple of hundred lines of code.  When in doubt, Keep It Simple, Stupid!

Comment: @bit-twiddler: Thank you for the complement. Sometimes it feels that hard won experience is no match for people who are determined to be 'right'.

Comment: @AndyT: The path to enlightenment is riddled with pot holes, snake oil salesmen, and the self-righteous.  However, there is nothing like having to wallow in one's own defecation for a sustained period of time to teach one to keep things simple.  There is nothing wrong with design patterns.  However, knowing design patterns is not the same thing as knowing software design.  No breakthrough software product has ever been built using a cookbook approach.  Designing high-performance software that meets requirements and is easy to maintain is still an art form that requires years to master.

Comment: I think another important reason to separate models, views and controllers is testability.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some interesting articles about implementing MVC Patterns, which might solve your problem.

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html
- http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1524

Answer (score 0):

If you develop a program with a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), [mvc pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is almost there but blurred.

Disecting model, view and controller code is difficult, and normally is not only a refactor task.

You know you have it when your code is reusable. If you have correctly implemented MVC, should be easy to implement a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) or a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) or a [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) or a [mobile first design](https://codemyviews.com/blog/mobilefirst) with the same functionality. It's easy to see it done than do it actually, moreover on an existing code.

In fact, interactions between model, view and controller happens using other isolation patterns (as Observer or Listener)

I guess this post explains it in detail, from the direct non MVC pattern (as you will do on a [Q&D](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quick-and-dirty)) to the final reusable implementation:

http://www.austintek.com/mvc/