# How Swing components implements MVC architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, swing

Suppose I have a JTextfield . How does only this JTextfield implement an MVC architecture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the controller in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831388/what-is-the-controller-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Java Swing components use MVC though its not always clear from the api. For each component there is a Controller, Model and View. JTextField, JButton, etc.. are all the Controllers. They also all support a getModel() which contains the state of the component. A lot of swing API pollute the controller api with convience methods so this is not always obvious. The text displayed in a JTextField is actually saved in the model. textField.getText() and textField.setText() are actually there for your convienence, what they really are doing is textField.getModel().getText() and textField.getModel().setText().

For the view there is a UI getComponentUI(). This is updated by propertyChanges fired from the Model. The ComponentUI is what lets different L&Fs be developed easily.

Comment: I think the model used by a TextField is a `Document`, exposed by `setDocument` and `getDocument`

Answer (score 3):

The Document is the Model.

Other than that a JTextField implements MVC the same as any other Swing component.