# JavaBean values empty with sql

Tags: java, sql, swing, listener, javabeans

```
    public void getEvent(String tableClick) {

    Events e = new Events();
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){      
        e.setEventName(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        e.setEventDate(rs.getDate(3));
        e.setEventTime(rs.getString(4));
        e.setEventVenue(rs.getString(5));
        e.setEventDetail(rs.getString(6));
        e.setEventOpportunity(rs.getString(7));
        e.setEventMoreDetails(rs.getString(8));
        e.setEndTime(rs.getString(9));
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
       }
    } 
    catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
} //end getEvent
```

Whilst the `System.out.println(rs.getString(2)` print a value from database, I am unable to populate this information in my bean.

I am using mutators to populate the `JavaBean`, but when I try to use the accessors in my View class of the MVC framework, it displays `null`.

Here is my Call from VIEW class

Method in VIEW class

```
     public void changeDisplay() {
       Events e = new Events();
       evTitle.setText(""+e.getEventName());
       evWhen.setText("When: "+ e.getEventDate());
       evWhere.setText("Where: "+ e.getEventVenue());
       evDescription.setText("Description: "+ e.getEventDetail());
       evOpportunity.setText("Opporunity: "+ e.getEventOpportunity());
       evMoreDet.setText("More Details: "+ e.getEventMoreDetails());
   }
```

Comment: nobody knows, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value instead of `JDBC`

Comment: @MooHa: Don't neglect to up-vote answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can't work... Why do you have a method called `getEvent` with a `void` return type? What you want is probably something like that :

```
public Event getEvent(String tableClick) {
Events e = new Events();
try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){      
    e.setEventName(rs.getString(2));
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    e.setEventDate(rs.getDate(3));
    e.setEventTime(rs.getString(4));
    e.setEventVenue(rs.getString(5));
    e.setEventDetail(rs.getString(6));
    e.setEventOpportunity(rs.getString(7));
    e.setEventMoreDetails(rs.getString(8));
    e.setEndTime(rs.getString(9));
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    return e;
   }
} catch(SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} 

} //end getEvent
```

I don't know how your code is working but you probably want to called that method from the view and then display the value. Your `changeDisplay` method is displaying `null` because you just created the object...

You probably need something like :

```
public void changeDisplay(Events e) {
    evTitle.setText(""+e.getEventName());
    evWhen.setText("When: "+ e.getEventDate());
    evWhere.setText("Where: "+ e.getEventVenue());
    evDescription.setText("Description: "+ e.getEventDetail());
    evOpportunity.setText("Opporunity: "+ e.getEventOpportunity());
    evMoreDet.setText("More Details: "+ e.getEventMoreDetails());
}
```

Comment: `Events e = object.getEvent("string");`  is not something I want to do. because I supply this argument in Controller?  any other ways?

Comment: It's an example, you can get it whatever you want and then pass it to the view as a parameter... I don't know how you have structure your application

Comment: thanks I was able to pass from my Controller to View. But I am curious  is it a good practice to pass from Controller. in the controller it has now `Events e = model.getEvent(tableClick);` and `view.changeDisplay(e);`, does it conform to the logic here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing)

Comment: I don't since I didn't saw your code. But if you are not sure, look at this example, it might help you : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html

Answer (score 0):

The `Events` you are creating in `changeDisplay()` method is a new object, not the one you populated in `getEvent`. You need to return/store the `e` from `getEvent` method and use it where ever required.

Answer (score 0):

In getEvent function you are creating an object of Events class and you are setting database values in it using setters.

But  in changeDisplay Function you are again creating an object of Events class and try to get values using getters.

```
public void changeDisplay() {
   Events e = new Events();
```

In place of creating new object of Events class in changeDisplay function you have to use the same object of Events class which you created in getEvent function.

Beacause you set the values in different object  and you are trying to get values from different object of Events class thats why it is showing null value to you.