# Calling a method from JFrame from another class

Tags: java, jframe

I am currently making a terrain generator, everything works fine in one class but I am going to be expanding my application.

Currently I have a JFrame class which holds everything, generating the terrain, painting the terrain, finding locations etc.

I want to add another class that will generate the terrain but when I create this class I need to access fields from the main JFrame class and when I do I get a stack overflow error - here is my code.

```
public class Simulator extends Applet
{
//fields

public Simulator()
{
    grid = new int[100][100];
    inhabGrid = new boolean[grid.length][grid.length];
    gridSize = grid.length - 1;
    dist = grid.length;
            TerrainGenerator gen = new TerrainGenerator();
    setSize(dist,dist);
    seedGrid();
    findInhabLocation();
    printGridToConsole();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)   
{
    //panting the grid
}

public void seedGrid()
{
    //seeding

}

public boolean generateTerrain(int x1,int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{

    //terrain generator
}

public boolean mouseUp(Event evt, int x, int y)
{
    seedGrid(); //Create a new map
    findInhabLocation();
    repaint();
    printGridToConsole();
    return true;
}

public boolean keyEvents(Event evt, int x, int y)
{
    seedGrid(); //Create a new map
    findInhabLocation();
    repaint();
    printGridToConsole();
    return true;
}

public void findInhabLocation()
{
    //find best inhabitant location
}

public int locateWater(int x, int y)
{

    //finding closest water
}

public int locateJungle(int x, int y)
{
    //finding closest jungle
}


}
}
```

That works fine in its own class but when I create a class for example:

```
public class TerrainGenerator 
{
Simulator sim = new Simulator();
}
```

I know this has something to do with the constructor and it's something silly I am doing, what would be the best way of splitting up this app into classes, for example terrain generator, inhabitants etc

For example I want to be able to call a method from the 'TerrainGenerator' class and call i.e. terrainGenerator.generateTerrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TerrainGenerator` creates a `Simulator` object and vice versa, hence you'll end up with infinitely many objects (but at some point the stack is full and a stack overflow exception is thrown instead...)

Instead of creating a new `Simulator` in your `TerrainGenerator`, you should pass a reference to your current `Simulator` (well, actually, that is not a great design either, but I'm not gonna confuse you with the problems of circular references).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I can see that the infinite loop is occurring, would you declare the TerrainGenerator in a field instead?

Comment: You could just make a constructor `TerrainGenerator(Simulator sim)` and call `new TerrainGenerator(this)`. That's not a good practice, and will result in a warning 'leaking this in constructor', but since your code is not multi-threaded, that is unlikely to be a real problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, is there any other way to go about this? I feel I am going about this problem in the wrong way, could I not create a new TerrainGenerator and have the methods arguments require what is needed to generate?

Comment: @Dowskiii yes for sure, that would be much cleaner. Ideally, you don't want `TerrainGenerator` to depend on `Simulator` at all. Passing everything you need as method parameters would be a much better design.

Comment: Or even better, use something like MVC, like Jorge Iten pointed out, but that will take some more effort.

Comment: From my understanding MVC seems like the way to go, I want to implement this as cleanly and as concise as possible, MVC has sort of like a 'middle man' which handles all of the data?

Comment: It's more like strictly separated data, a view on that data, and a 'middle man', the controller, that instantiates both and can manipulate the data, based on interactions with the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll start the implementation now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Heuster answer is correct, furthermore, I think you could take look at  [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing) to help you organize your classes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. So here I should have a 'middle man' that deals with the data, I can then create an instance of that object to retrieve the data for me?

Comment: Yes, the controller is the 'middle man'. You can call the controller  whenever the view change.

Answer (score 0):

Depending which should be the parent, you can pass in the instantiated class to the other, ie;

```
private final TerrainGenerator gen;  //if you need to save this.
public Simulator(TerrainGenerator terrainGenerator)
{

  this.gen = terrainGenerator;
 ....etc
}


public class TerrainGenerator 
{
Simulator sim = new Simulator(this);
}
```

or

```
private final TerrainGenerator gen;  //if you need to save this.
public Simulator()
{

  this.gen = new TerrainGenerator(this);
 ....etc
}

private final Simulator sim; //If you need to save it.
public class TerrainGenerator 
{
  public TerrainGenerator(Simulator simulator) {
    this.sim = simulator;
  }
}
```