# What's a good-practice replacement of System.out.println?

Tags: java, swing, printing, console

My application has to output content for the user. Throughout all my classes I've just been using System.out.println, but since the program isn't intended to be run by command line this isn't really suitable.

I had thought of simply making a classes that extends JPanel and having all the content append to a textarea. I've been reading that this isn't a good move, and an issue arises in that I'll have to pass the JPanel class to all the classes that output text.

Is there a good-practice alternative to System.out.println? If not, how do you suggest I proceed? I have suggestions of Java Logging, but I don't want to output to a file.

Comment: You should have limited user interaction in most of your classes and in fact the UI code should be separate in its own set of class. You should strive to write your model (non-UI) code so that it can work well in a console application, a Swing application, an SWT application or other UI library type application. This way your code can work with SOP or with GUI's as you see fit. I will wager that > 90% of Java classes created by professional coders have no UI code within them.

Comment: + the general design is wrong

Answer (score 3):

You should have limited user interaction in most of your classes and in fact the UI code should be separate in its own set of class. You should strive to write your model (non-UI) code so that it can work well in a console application, a Swing application, an SWT application or other UI library type application. This way your code can work with SOP or with GUI's as you see fit. I will wager that > 90% of Java classes created by professional coders have no UI code within them.

Also please note that logging and user interaction code are two completely orthogonal concepts. I look at logging as a way to communicate with the developer and supporter, not the user.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Hovercraft's comment. Don't pass the JPanel, have a `static` method in your UI class that all other objects call when they need to output. That method will handle formatting and appending and all that.

Moreover there isn't really an alternative to `println` when it comes to Java. That's because println only outputs to stdout and in a GUI application it's hidden unless the user executes your program from command line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm fairly noob and I don't think my coding practices are up to scratch. My main() method is inside my UI class. All the classes that use System.out.println are instantiated in the UI class. The console style output box that I'm trying to use is a JPanel, with a JTextArea, that is also instantiated in the UI class. If I have a static method in the UI class that appends text to the console, my understanding is that the static method won't be available to the rest of the classes, which leaves me with the same problem of having to pass the JPanel as a parameter.. no?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I found a fix. I'll know to do this differently next time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, a method declared static can be called from anywhere it is visible, without the need to instantiate its class (that's why `main` is static). Only `public` `private` and related keywords affect visibility within a package. I understand you only have one class, that's not really a good idea and not the way Java is supposed to be. Break it up. Keep the `main` class to do initialization, a GUI class for the UI and any other classes for processing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a configurable logging framework, like Log4j. By writing a custom log appender, you have have your log output appear anywhere you want, not just in a file: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2004/jw-1220-toolbox.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that sending messages to stdout is usually inappropriate in a production environment. If you're coding a library, the library should return information to its caller, not print to stdout. If you're coding a GUI app, the information should be presented to the user, not to where stdout happens to be pointing (which might be nowhere). If you're coding a server (or something that runs in a server-side container) you should be using whatever logging facility the framework has provided. And so forth.

The logger gives to ability to define different levels of importance of the logged messages and the ability to use different sink for the output - the console, a file, etc.

Also it's easy to enable or disable only some type of message when using a logger - for example you don't want to see every debug message in production.

I don't think that using loggers offers any significant advantages in unit tests, but I'd prefer it even there anyways. In unit tests asserts are usually my primary concern.

Btw you should really consider using something like [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) or [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) as a log framework facade - it's bad style to tie your code to a specific logging framework. Common Logging and SLF4J make it easy to switch logging frameworks if you choose to.

Answer (score 1):

The best method to output information to your user depends on the kind of app you're working on.

If your app is batch-oriented and highly technical, it might be appropriate to send output to a scrolling text area (JTextArea) so users can view the latest status and scroll back to get details if they want.

But if it's more interactive and less technical in nature, you should try to minimize output to only the most essential things, like high-level status messages, or critical error messages. Simple dialogues (JOptionPane) and status bars (JLabel) might be best in that case.

In either case, if your app is large, you should consider designing it so that you don't scatter a lot of UI code in with everything else. Keeping the main logic separate from the presentation code will help with maintenance later on. One well-accepted approach to doing that is called model-view-controller (MVC).

Here are a couple good links to get you started on MVC.

- [Wikipedia article on Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)
- [Stackoverflow question: The MVC pattern and SWING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing)

Answer (score -3):

> Is there a good-practice alternative to System.out.println?

return