# Using an interface to update a GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, interface, jtextarea

I was told by an experienced developer that it's a bad idea to pass around an instance of a GUI.

Basically I have a class that builds and displays a GUI.  In an actionListener I create an object that does some time intensive tasks and I wanted to display a status as certain milestones of the task are completed.

Here is a very simplified version of the class:

```
public class MyGui extends JFrame {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private JPanel mainPanel;
   private JPanel selectionPanel;
   private JPanel activityPanel;
   private JPanel executePanel;

   private JButton connectButton;
   private JButton disconnectButton;
   private JButton abortButton;

   private JList aList;

   private JComboBox comboBox;

   private JRadioButton primaryButton;
   private JRadioButton secondaryButton;

   private static JTextArea activityTextArea;

   MyGui() {

      this.setTitle("My Tool");

      mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      mainPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      this.add(mainPanel);

      createMainSelectionArea();
      createNodeSelectionArea();
      createStatusArea();
      createExecuteArea();

      mainPanel.add(selectionPanel);
      mainPanel.add(activityPanel);
      mainPanel.add(executePanel);

      this.add(mainPanel);
      this.setResizable(false);

      addActivity("test1");
      addActivity("test2");
      addActivity("test3");
      addActivity("test4");
      addActivity("test5");
      addActivity("test6");

      this.setSize(600, 400);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   private void createMainSelectionArea() {

      RadioButtonListener radioButtonListener = new RadioButtonListener();

      primaryButton = new JRadioButton("Primary");
      primaryButton.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      primaryButton.setForeground(Color.white);
      primaryButton.addActionListener(radioButtonListener);

      secondaryButton = new JRadioButton("Secondary");
      secondaryButton.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      secondaryButton.setForeground(Color.white);
      secondaryButton.addActionListener(radioButtonListener);

      ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      buttonGroup.add(primaryButton);
      buttonGroup.add(secondaryButton);

      JPanel buttonGroupPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      buttonGroupPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      buttonGroupPanel.setOpaque(true);
      buttonGroupPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      buttonGroupPanel.setForeground(Color.white);
      buttonGroupPanel.add(primaryButton);
      buttonGroupPanel.add(secondaryButton);

      selectionPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
      selectionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      selectionPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      selectionPanel.add(buttonGroupPanel);
   }

   private void createNodeSelectionArea() {

      String[] data1 = {"one", "two", "three", "4", "5", "6"};
      String[] data2 = {"four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"};

      ComboBoxListener comboBoxListener = new ComboBoxListener();

      comboBox = new JComboBox(data1);
      comboBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));
      comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));;
      comboBox.setBackground(Color.white);
      comboBox.setForeground(Color.black);
      comboBox.addActionListener(comboBoxListener);

      JPanel comboBoxPanel = new JPanel();
      comboBoxPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      comboBoxPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      comboBoxPanel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      ListBoxListener listBoxListener = new ListBoxListener();

      aList = new JList(data2);
      aList.setBackground(Color.black);
      aList.setForeground(Color.white);
      aList.addListSelectionListener(listBoxListener);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(aList);
      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      scrollPane.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

      JPanel listBoxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
      TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("A Selection");
      border.setTitleColor(Color.white);
      border.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));

      listBoxPanel.setBorder(border);
      listBoxPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      listBoxPanel.setForeground(Color.white);
      listBoxPanel.add(scrollPane);

      selectionPanel.add(comboBoxPanel);
      selectionPanel.add(listBoxPanel);
   }

   private void createStatusArea() {

      activityTextArea = new JTextArea();
      activityTextArea.setEditable(false);
      activityTextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      activityTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
      activityTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(activityTextArea);
      scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      scrollPane.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

      TitledBorder activityTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Status");
      activityTitle.setTitleColor(Color.white);
      activityTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));
      activityTitle.setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.CENTER);

      activityPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
      activityPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      activityPanel.setBorder(activityTitle);
      activityPanel.add(scrollPane);
   }

   public void addActivity(String activity) {

      activityTextArea.append(activity + "\n");
      activityTextArea.setCaretPosition(activityTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
   }

   public void createExecuteArea() {

      ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();

      connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
      connectButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(115, 30));
      connectButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray)));
      connectButton.setBackground(Color.white);
      connectButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

      disconnectButton = new JButton("Disconnect");
      disconnectButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(115, 30));
      disconnectButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray)));
      disconnectButton.setBackground(Color.white);
      disconnectButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

      abortButton = new JButton("Abort");
      abortButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(115, 30));
      abortButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray)));
      abortButton.setBackground(Color.white);
      abortButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);

      executePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      executePanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

      buttonPanel.add(connectButton);
      buttonPanel.add(disconnectButton);
      buttonPanel.add(abortButton);

      executePanel.add(buttonPanel, c);
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         if(e.getSource().equals(connectButton)) { 

            System.out.println("Connect Button"); 
         }

         if(e.getSource().equals(disconnectButton)) { 

            System.out.println("Disconnect Button"); 
         }

         if(e.getSource().equals(abortButton)) { 

            System.out.println("Abort Button"); 
         }
      }
   }

   private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         if(e.getSource().equals(primaryButton)) {

            System.out.println("Primary Selected");
         }

         if(e.getSource().equals(secondaryButton)) {

            System.out.println("Secondary Selected");
         }
      }
   }

   private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         if(e.getSource().equals(comboBox)) {

            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(MyGui.this, otherStuff);
            dataClass.doStuff();  // This class was calling the addActivity() method.
         }
      }
   }

   private class ListBoxListener implements ListSelectionListener {

      @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

         if(e.getSource().equals(aList)) {

            System.out.println(aList.getSelectedValue());
         }
      }
   }

}
```

So I was passing (assuming the class is named MyGui) `MyGui.this` to the `DataClass` in question and then using `addActivity("status update");`

So instead of doing the above, I created this interface:

```
public interface GuiUpdater {

   void update(MyGui MyGui, String update);
}
```

and modified the `MyGui` class above to implement the interface and call it this way:

```
   @Override
   public void update(MyGui myGui, String update) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      myGui.addActivity(update);
   }
```

and so I could update it from the other classes where I also implemented this interface. So I passed an instance of MyGui from main to the other classes.

I think this is doing the same thing as I was doing before, though (just differently).

Is this the right way of using an interface, and if not, what is the proper way to update a GUI from a different class without passing an instance of a GUI?

Comment: If your MyGui class is implementing the interface, why the MyGui parameter to the method? Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think that is part of my confusion.  How do I update the textArea from other classes without the MyGui parameter?  It IS redundant in the MyGui class - you're correct.

Comment: Are you familiar with the MCV design pattern, model-view-control? That's what many folks use, and you'd link the model and the view (the GUI) through the control.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not familiar with MCV, but I will look into it.

Comment: I suggest that you look into that, including searching this site on the combination of [tag:swing] and [tag:model-view-control] tags. And once you understand that, look into dependency injection.

Comment: I follow @HovercraftFullOfEels advice, get into MVC with Swing and you'll solve your problem when you get the idea behind MVC. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing

I also know a paid (like $30 or something) Swing online course but I'm afraid I can't post it here, someone correct me if I'm wrong. I did it and since then I understood Swing quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are used to define methods that an object can support without requiring consumers of the interface to know much about the object or how it wishes to implement the interface.  In your situation, you wish to provide an update method onto `MyGui` that will not require a tight coupling between the `MyGui` class and your other code.  If you define your interface as such, then you can write all of your code that may need to update the GUI to interact only with an object of type `GuiUpdater`:

```
public interface GuiUpdater {

   void update(String update);
}
```

You would then modify your `MyGui` class declaration to implement this interface:

```
public class MyGui extends JFrame implements GuiUpdater {
```

You will also have to implement this method inside `MyGui`:

```
@Override
public void update(String update) {
     this.addActivity(update);
}
```

This is similar to what you have in the question, with one important difference.  Because it's implemented as a method inside `MyGui`, you have access to all of the internal state of your `MyGui` instance (such as `this`).  In other words, you don't need to pass a `MyGui` instance as a parameter, since this method is inside `MyGui`.

Now, we can assume you an instance of `MyGui` called `myGui` have a function that might want to update the GUI, such as:

```
public void foo(GuiUpdater updater) {
    updater.update("Interfaces are great");
}
```

You can call this function like `foo(myGui)` because `MyGui` satisfies that interface.  This decouples the implementation of `foo` from the implementation of `MyGui`, and means that either side is insulated from changes to the other side's implementation.

Irrespective of how you architect your software (MVC, MVP, etc), coding to interfaces is a good habit to get into.  It hides implementation details, and as such, reduces the impact of changing those details down the line.