# Trying to follow MVC Pattern

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build my first JAVA Swing application using the MVC pattern. But I dont quite crasp it. Especially not on how to code it. I read a lot on this site and other sites about MVC.
This is one of the things I read about MVC:
[The MVC pattern and SWING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing/5217977#5217977)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm

I am fairly new to developing and want to start from the beginning using best practices.

What I think I understand about the MVC pattern is you have a *Controller* a *Model* and a *View*. The *Controller* gets it input from the *View*. Then the *Controller* ask the *Model* to change it state. Gets the state back from the *Model* and does everyting it needs to do with the input like storing it to a database or change the *View* with what it gets back from the database.

For example if a button "add Address" is clicked it gets the input from the textfields in the *View*. The *Controller* updates the *Model* and saves the data it gets from the *View* into the database. If the button "search Addres" is clicked it gets it input from the textfield in the *View* searches the database and if it gets data back it updates the *Model* and outputs it in the *View*.

If what I think to know about *MVC* is right how do I code this?

Is it possible to explane it using the code I have so far?

How can I get the data from the *View* to the *Controller* and on to the *Model*?

This is my code so far:

*View JFrame*

```
public class WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form StoringAdresses1JFrame
     */
    public WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        firstName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lastName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        emailAdress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        searchEmailAdress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        removeEmailAddress = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        street = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        number = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        additive = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        zipCode = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        city = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addAdress = new javax.swing.JButton();
        removeAdress = new javax.swing.JButton();
        searchAdress = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        showInputOutput = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Address Input Fields", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("First Name:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Last Name:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Email Adress:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Street / Number / Add");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Zipcode / City");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Email Address:");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Email Address:");

        firstName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        lastName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        emailAdress.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        street.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        number.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        additive.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        zipCode.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        city.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 11)); // NOI18N

        addAdress.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        addAdress.setText("Add Address");
        ActionListener actionListener = new MainWindowActionListenerMVCVIEW(firstName, lastName, emailAdress, street, number, additive, zipCode, city, searchEmailAdress, removeEmailAddress);
        addAdress.addActionListener(actionListener);

        removeAdress.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        removeAdress.setText("Remove Address");
        removeAdress.setBackground(Color.RED);
        removeAdress.addActionListener(actionListener);

        searchAdress.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        searchAdress.setText("Search Address");
        searchAdress.addActionListener(actionListener);


        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(firstName)
                            .addComponent(lastName)
                            .addComponent(emailAdress)
                            .addComponent(searchEmailAdress)
                            .addComponent(removeEmailAddress)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(street, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(number, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 49, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(additive, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(zipCode, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 114, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(city)
                        .addContainerGap())))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(addAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(removeAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(searchAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                        .addComponent(firstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lastName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(emailAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(street, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(number, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(additive, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(zipCode, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(city, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(addAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)

                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(removeEmailAddress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(removeAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(searchEmailAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(searchAdress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(203, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Show Input / Show Search", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14))); // NOI18N

        showInputOutput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(showInputOutput);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 349, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }                  
    private javax.swing.JButton addAdress;
    private javax.swing.JButton removeAdress;
    private javax.swing.JButton searchAdress;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    public javax.swing.JTextArea showInputOutput;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField firstName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField lastName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField emailAdress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchEmailAdress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField removeEmailAddress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField street;
    private javax.swing.JTextField number;
    private javax.swing.JTextField additive;
    private javax.swing.JTextField zipCode;
    private javax.swing.JTextField city;                
}
```

*View ActionListener*

```
public class MainWindowActionListenerMVCVIEW implements ActionListener {
    public  JTextField firstName, lastName, emailAddress, street, number, additive, zipCode, city, searchEmailAdress, removeEmailAddress;


    public MainWindowActionListenerMVCVIEW(JTextField fName, JTextField lName, JTextField eAddress, JTextField streetName, JTextField houseNumber, JTextField add, JTextField zCode, JTextField cityName, JTextField searchEAdress, JTextField removeEAddress) {

        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.emailAddress = eAddress;
        this.street = streetName;
        this.number = houseNumber;
        this.additive = add;
        this.zipCode = zCode;
        this.city = cityName;
        this.searchEmailAdress = searchEAdress;
        this.removeEmailAddress = removeEAddress;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        firstName.getText();
        lastName.getText();
        emailAddress.getText();
        street.getText();
        number.getText();
        additive.getText();
        zipCode.getText();
        city.getText();
        searchEmailAdress.getText();
        removeEmailAddress.getText();
        System.out.println("test" + " " + firstName.getText()); // I put this in just te see if the *ActionListener* works

     }
}
```

*Model*

```
public class WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String emailAddress;
    public String street;
    public String number;
    public String additive;
    public String zipCode;
    public String city;
}
```

*Controller*

```
public class WolffAddressManagerMVCController {
    public WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL controllerModel;
    public MainWindowActionListenerMVCVIEW controllerActionListener;
    public WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW controllerJFrame;
    private Connection connect = null;
    private final Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    public ArrayList<String> queryResultSet = new ArrayList();

    public void saveAddressToDataBase(MainWindowActionListenerMVCVIEW controller) throws Exception {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev?" + "user=root&password=password");
            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT email FROM dev.addresses WHERE email= '" + controller.emailAddress.getText() + "'");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if(resultSet.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Email already exist", "InfoBox: " + "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  dev.addresses (firstname, lastname, email, street, housenumber, additve, zipcode, city) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, controller.firstName.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, controller.lastName.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, controller.emailAddress.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, controller.street.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(5, controller.number.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(6, controller.additive.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(7, controller.zipCode.getText());
                preparedStatement.setString(8, controller.city.getText());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
          throw e;
        } finally {
          close();
        }
    }

    public void searchAddress(String emailAddress) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev?" + "user=root&password=fiat128slc");
            preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dev.addresses WHERE email= '" + emailAddress + "'");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if(resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
                while(resultSet.next()) {
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("email"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("street"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("housenumber"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("additve"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("zipcode"));
                    queryResultSet.add(resultSet.getString("city"));
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email doesn't exist", "InfoBox: " + "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
          throw e;
        } finally {
          close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my last answer. I think I am on the right track. Using getters and setters in my MVC project. I now have a Class who takes care of the queries.

*Controller*

```
    public class WolffAddressManagerMVCController {
    private final WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model;
    private final WolffAddressManagerQueriesMVCSERVICES query;

    public WolffAddressManagerMVCController(WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) {
        this.query = new WolffAddressManagerQueriesMVCSERVICES();
        this.model = model;
    }


    public void buildView() throws Exception {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

    public void buildView2() throws Exception {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WolffAddressManagerMVCUpdateJFrameVIEW.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new WolffAddressManagerMVCUpdateJFrameVIEW().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

    public void addCredentials(WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW view , WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) throws Exception {
        if(model.getEmailAddress().equals(model.getReTypeEmailAddress())) {
            if(query.saveAddressToDataBase(view, model) == true) {
                showCredentials(view);
            }
            else {
                view.setTextArea(view.getTextArea() + "EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS\n\n");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Emailaddresses are not the same", "InfoBox: " + "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private void showCredentials(WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW view) throws Exception {
        DefaultListModel<String> jList = new DefaultListModel();
        JList<String> list = new JList(jList);
        model.setSearchResultArray(searchCredentials(model));
        for(int i = 0; i < model.getSearchResultArray().size(); i++) {
            jList.addElement(model.getSearchResultArray().get(i));
        }
        list.setModel(jList);

        int size = list.getModel().getSize();
        StringBuilder credentials = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           credentials.append(list.getModel().getElementAt(i)).append("\n");
        }
        view.setTextArea(view.getTextArea() + credentials.toString()+ "CREDENTIALS ADDED\n\n");
    }

    public void removeCredentials() throws Exception {
        query.removeAddress(model.getEmailAddress());
    }

    public ArrayList<String> searchCredentials(WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) throws Exception {
        return query.searchAddress(model.getEmailAddress());
    }

    public void showSearchResult(WolffAddressManagerMVCJFrameVIEW view, WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) {
        DefaultListModel<String> jList = new DefaultListModel();
        JList<String> list = new JList(jList);

        try {
            model.setSearchResultArray(searchCredentials(model));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindowActionListenerSearchMVCVIEW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } 
        for(int i = 0; i < model.getSearchResultArray().size(); i++) {
            jList.addElement(model.getSearchResultArray().get(i));
        }
        list.setModel(jList);

        int size = list.getModel().getSize();
        StringBuilder credentials = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           credentials.append(list.getModel().getElementAt(i)).append("\n");
        }
        view.setTextArea(view.getTextArea() + credentials.toString());
    }

    private void showUpdateResult(WolffAddressManagerMVCUpdateJFrameVIEW view, WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) {
        DefaultListModel<String> jList = new DefaultListModel();
        JList<String> list = new JList(jList);

        try {
            model.getUpdateResultArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindowActionListenerSearchMVCVIEW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } 
        for(int i = 0; i < model.getUpdateResultArray().size(); i++) {
            jList.addElement(model.getUpdateResultArray().get(i));
        }
        list.setModel(jList);

        int size = list.getModel().getSize();
        StringBuilder credentials = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           credentials.append(list.getModel().getElementAt(i)).append("\n");
        }
        view.setTextArea(credentials.toString());
    }

    public void updateCredentials(WolffAddressManagerMVCUpdateJFrameVIEW view,WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model) throws Exception {
        if(query.updateAddress(view, model) == true) {
            showUpdateResult(view,model);
        }
    }
}
```

*Model*

```
       public class WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL {
    private String updateEmailAddress;
    private String companyName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String reTypeEmailAddress;
    private String street;
    private String number;
    private String additive;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private JTextField jTextFieldUpdateEmailAddress;
    private JTextField jTextFieldCompanyName;
    private JTextField jTextFieldFirstName;
    private JTextField jTextFieldLastName;
    private JTextField jTextFieldEmailAddress;
    private JTextField jTextFieldReTypeEmailAddress;
    private JTextField jTextFieldStreetName;
    private JTextField jTextFieldHouseNumber;
    private JTextField jTextFieldAdditive;
    private JTextField jTextFieldZipCode;
    private JTextField jTextFieldCityName;
    private JTextField jTextFieldSearchEmailAddress;
    private JTextField jTextFieldRemoveEmailAddress;
    private ArrayList<String> searchResultArray = null;
    private ArrayList<String> updateResultArray = null;

    public String getUpdateEmailAddress() {
        return updateEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setUpdateEmailAddress(String updateEmailAddress) {
        this.updateEmailAddress = updateEmailAddress;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getReTypeEmailAddress() {
        return reTypeEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setReTypeEmailAddress(String reTypeEmailAddress) {
        this.reTypeEmailAddress = reTypeEmailAddress;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getAdditive() {
        return additive;
    }

    public void setAdditive(String additive) {
        this.additive = additive;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldUpdateEmailAddress() {
        return jTextFieldUpdateEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldUpdateEmailAddress(JTextField updateEmailAddress) {
        this.jTextFieldUpdateEmailAddress = updateEmailAddress;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldCompanyName() {
        return jTextFieldCompanyName;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldCompanyName(JTextField companyName) {
        this.jTextFieldCompanyName = companyName;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldFirstName() {
        return jTextFieldFirstName;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldFirstName(JTextField fName) {
        this.jTextFieldFirstName = fName;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldLastName() {
        return jTextFieldLastName;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldLastName(JTextField lastName) {
        this.jTextFieldLastName = lastName;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldEmailAddress() {
        return jTextFieldEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldEmailAddress(JTextField emailAddress) {
        this.jTextFieldEmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldReTypeEmailAddress() {
        return jTextFieldReTypeEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldReTypeEmailAddress( JTextField reTypeEmailAddress) {
        this.jTextFieldReTypeEmailAddress = reTypeEmailAddress;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldStreet() {
        return jTextFieldStreetName;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldStreet(JTextField streetName) {
        this.jTextFieldStreetName = streetName;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldHouseNumber() {
        return jTextFieldHouseNumber;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldHouseNumber(JTextField houseNumber) {
        this.jTextFieldHouseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextfieldAdditive() {
        return jTextFieldAdditive;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldAdditive(JTextField additive) {
        this.jTextFieldAdditive = additive;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldZipCode() {
        return jTextFieldZipCode;
    }

    public void setJTexFieldZipCode(JTextField zipCode) {
        this.jTextFieldZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldCity() {
        return jTextFieldCityName;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldCity(JTextField cityName){
        this.jTextFieldCityName = cityName;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldSearchEmailAddress(){
        return jTextFieldSearchEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldSearchEmailAddress(JTextField searchEmailAddress) {
        this.jTextFieldSearchEmailAddress = searchEmailAddress;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextFieldRemoveEmailAddress(){
        return jTextFieldRemoveEmailAddress;
    }

    public void setJTextFieldRemoveEmailAddress(JTextField removeEAddress){
        this.jTextFieldRemoveEmailAddress = removeEAddress;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSearchResultArray() {
        return searchResultArray;
    }

    public void setSearchResultArray(ArrayList searchResultArray) {
        this.searchResultArray = searchResultArray;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUpdateResultArray() {
        return updateResultArray;
    }

    public void setUpdateResultArray(ArrayList searchResultArray) {
        this.updateResultArray = searchResultArray;
    }
}
```

And here is one of my ActionListener Classes in total I have 4 of these classes to perform Create, Read, Update and Delete on my database.

```
 public class MainWindowActionListenerAddMVCVIEW implements ActionListener {

    WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL model = new WolffAddressManagerMVCMODEL();
    WolffAddressManagerMVCController controller = new WolffAddressManagerMVCController(model);
    public MainWindowActionListenerAddMVCVIEW(JTextField fName, JTextField lName, JTextField eAddress, JTextField streetName, JTextField houseNumber, JTextField add, JTextField zCode, JTextField cityName) {

        this.model.setJTextfiedFirstName(fName);
        this.model.setJTextFieldLastName(lName);
        this.model.setJTextFieldEmailAddress(eAddress);
        this.model.setJTextFieldStreet(streetName);
        this.model.setJTextFieldHouseNumber(houseNumber);
        this.model.setJTextFieldAdditive(add);
        this.model.setJTexFieldZipCode(zCode);
        this.model.setJTextFieldCity(cityName);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.setFirstName(model.getJTextFieldFirstName().getText());
        model.setLastName(model.getJTextFieldLastName().getText());
        model.setEmailAddress(model.getJTextFieldEmailAddress().getText());
        model.setStreet(model.getJTextFieldStreet().getText());
        model.setNumber(model.getJTextFieldHouseNumber().getText());
        model.setAdditive(model.getJTextfieldAdditive().getText());
        model.setZipCode(model.getJTextFieldZipCode().getText());
        model.setCity(model.getJTextFieldCity().getText());
        try {
            controller.saveAddressToDataBase(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindowActionListenerAddMVCVIEW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```